# Origin of "despicable"

Tags: etymology

I was looking at the wikiquote of Daffy Duck, when I noticed the word *despicable*. What is its origin? Is it Latin or Greek?

Comment: http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?search=despicable&searchmode=none

Comment: I started to use this word much often after watching the movie "Despicable Me"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's from late Latin *despicabilis*, from *despicari* ("look down on").